# Displaying stored procedure query while calling procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I created a stored procedure like this and called that procedure with input arguments. I want to get the procedure it self while calling it with arguments just like echo query in normal case.

```
            $procedure              =   "CREATE PROCEDURE pdruser_login(IN userName VARCHAR(300), IN password VARCHAR(500)) 
                                        BEGIN 
                                        DECLARE _sqlQuery VARCHAR(2046);
                                        SET _sqlQuery = 'SELECT login_id, authorized, admin_authorize FROM tbluser_login WHERE user_name = userName AND user_pwd = password AND authorized = 1 AND privacy_policy = 1 AND is_deleted = 0';
                                        SET @sqlQuery = _sqlQuery;
                                        PREPARE dynquery FROM @sqlQuery;
                                        EXECUTE dynquery;
                                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynquery;
                                        END;";              
            if (!mysqli_query($this->con,"DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pdruser_login") ||!mysqli_query($this->con,$procedure))
                {
                    file_put_contents("minefile1.txt", "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . mysqli_errno($this->con) . ") " . mysqli_error($this->con));
                }
            if (!($result   =   mysqli_query($this->con,"CALL pdruser_login('".$userName."','".$password."'"))) 
                {
                    file_put_contents("minefile2.txt","CALL failed: (" . mysqli_errno($this->con) . ") " . mysqli_error($this->con));
                }
```

But the above procedure shows an error "CALL failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1".

How can I display the stored procedure query while calling the stored procedure.Is there is any way for getting the dynamic query so it will be easy to trace the errors in complex queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you don't store your SQL in a variable - so, you cannot have it in your debug info

```
$sql = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pdruser_login";
mysqli_query($this->con,$sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->con)." [$sql]");
$sql = $procedure;
mysqli_query($this->con,$sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->con)." [$sql]");
// and so on.
```

note that trigger_error is a way more useful that file_put_contents. it can put the error in a log file but also it can display it on-screen which id very handy. And it have indispensable file/line stamp

Answer (score 0):

First for creating a MySQL procedure you need to set DELIMITER other than ; then reset delimiter after procedure execution as Inside priocedure all bock should treat as single query but query inside procedure can break sql statement (due to using ;)

Example from mysql site.

```
DELIMITER // 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllProducts //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts() 
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM products; 
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```